# How do I select options in a select element with pyselenium?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, web-crawler

This doesn't seem to work:

```
select_input = self.ff.find_element_by_name(select_name)
select_input.select_by_value(option_val)
```

yet it seems `select_by_value` would be the most obvious choice.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the appropriate option element and `.click()` it:

```
select_input = self.ff.find_element_by_name(select_name)
option = select_input.find_element_by_xpath("option[value=%s]" % option_val)
option.click()
```

Comment: note that if the element is not found the xpath seems to hang, so one best probably loop through all the option elements the ugly way